# Adding Image to xCode by dragging it from File

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios5, xcode4

I'm having trouble adding an image in xCode 4.2. When I'm inserting an `UIimageview` into the `ViewController` by dragging it from my desktop, it won't work.

Is there any other possible ways to add an image?

Comment: First add the image file to your project

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't add image from desktop to `UIimageView`, you only can add image (dragging) into project folders and then select the name image into `UIimageView` properties (inspector).

Tutorial on how to do that: http://conecode.com/news/2011/06/ios-tutorial-creating-an-image-view-uiimageview/

Comment: link is broken.

Answer (score 34):

Add the image to Your project by clicking File -> "Add Files to ...".

Then choose the image in ImageView properties (Utilities -> Attributes Inspector).

Answer (score 0):

For xCode 10, first you need to add the image in your assetsCatalogue and then type this:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "type the name of your image here..."))
```

For beginners, `let imageView` is the name of the `UIImageView` object we are about to create.

An example for embedding an image into a `viewControler` file would look like this:

```
import UIKit

class TutorialViewCotroller: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "intoImage"))
        view.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```

Please notice that I did not use any extension for the image file name, as in my case it is a group of images.